# How can I get this to normal language? What is it?

Tags: character-encoding

Someone encoded so many files on my machine - please help!  Don't know a thing about this.

>4˜ÙSc8!¹ëe%£÷2˜9žÙq^3î/Úœ€ÕäÏòÉ:©ÓS@ÞFÚ¡NÂ;î ÜYHiŠþnŸtr†sèàa
çB6»ä  ßè%y×y¦”
uçk£îl°&ø˜€ŒÂ@ÜòZ‰4ð‚öý ¥¨”øÐÝ ·©¹6ÄËbD¼Ym‰-Q#õ’ÑªZH
%zŽhŠõY¼EV¼§°Éé:ßú-Ö]u*Ë?£ÍžLËã\wVj«­.gkƒñîLµ‚yßH@¸×ç0·§¡2rÌ€3®(FÓð]Qkâ(áñsäo
tX©™O7Ñ„ÂÝc{Í(›;DQ¶´CÜC$þŒS2‰éS'YilÀ!G1 ˆøù!›;ŒÁø“_U£‡vÃvÇþzðxº£µË!ÿìÐÏw©€:q:‚9j´®‡z¢ÿ“‹i˜Mû°”+üµÜÊwe´û¤„ÿÁÌ:)‡¶Q%Ãà¹4ÉÒc}üpCëZÅ|,ïì-0q3rŸ‡½E; ÜƒC¿+º§½8³™§3B[Û*i(/Žq?°ÐýÈÞ98Ä”¤Â«J-‚ýAƒyb‘•@¾XõüƒÓJìß>ä¼ø‰ 2xÊxh6|.äFß5ß¶å‘àØxÝÎöpòXÿ¸î/Ø›ÓÉn-åï´øx®ë#jBSvöÄ„Ýû[qwyôœ³`WÇž•ÌÓJÜw‡¿Ùhœã·÷ÆT$žƒmm”&ºS­p¡a‹&¯ÈhÿK˜ÕùÿÏô•_8„ÚXÐ

Willing to learn and willing to hire someone to help

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like encryption, I think you opened a file you shouldn't have in notepad. If not, can you try to provide a little more background?

Comment: Hi.  Sure. It's saved as a .txt file.  I think someone renames files so I can't open. The only thing I can see on the top that looks like plain english is cbd file ripl_board_record.  It's like they are hiding something from me on my own laptop.